# auto keyword in C++

Tags: c++, auto

Why C++ compiler doesn't guess that its `initializer_list` and not `int`?>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {
    auto f = 45; // int, fine.
    auto li {12,2,54,65}; // initializer_list, as expected/
    auto A{12};  // ????
    std::cout<<typeid(A).name()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does it say? I'd expect it to be a `signed integer` or not compile at all.

Comment: Does that code compile with some compiler; if so, which one?

Comment: @sbooth: please refrain from "correcting" the code of a question. that changes the question (unless you really know what you're doing).

Comment: sorry for error. EDIT

Comment: @Gui_C: oh well, with latest edit i can report that both mingw g++ and visual c++ deduce the type as `initializer_list<int>`. i wouldn't have expected it to compile. learning something new...

Comment: Only N3922 changes the rules making things simpler and more intuitive, so that without equals operator you get `int`, and `auto li{1,2,3}` is a compiler error, which compiler are you using and what is actually your question?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I added a missing semicolon, which was clearly an error not related to the question itself.